# I'm getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND whenever i import my decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

My project is a back-end using Express. I was trying to create an automated swagger using decorators. Then i created a file called `decorators.ts` and a file called `dynamic-loader.ts`.
My dynamic loader just use `import` in each file inside a controllers folder. Inside my `decorators.ts` i have many decorators just like the following:

```
    ...

    export function ApiController(route: string, name?: string) {
        return function (
            target: any
        ) {
            target.prototype.route = route;
            target.prototype.tag = name ?? (<string>target.name).replace(/Controller/g, '');
        };
    }
    
    export function AllowAnonymous(
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) {
        descriptor.value.anonymous = true;
    }

    ...
```

The problem is that whenever i import any of my decorators into my controller i got this error:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'src/lib/decorators'
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed every single dependency again using yarn and now it works.